# AutoIt DllCall() shell32.dll

Tags: windows-7, autoit

How to setup Windows 7 user tiles via a script I found explained in [a blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110701000906/http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/). But I do not want the .NET framework dependency this requires, so I try to call it directly via [DllCall()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DllCall.htm). However I cannot get this to work:

```
#RequireAdmin
FileCopy("user_tile.jpg", "C:\Windows\system32\user_tile.jpg")
$rtn = DllCall(@SystemDir & "\shell32.dll", "long", 262, "wstr", "ahiscox", "int", 0, "wstr", "C:\Windows\system32\user_tile.jpg")
MsgBox(16, "DLL Return", $rtn[0])
```

I got a return value of -2147024894 (seems shell32.dll wasn't finding user_tile.jpg). After changing to wstr this returns -2147221008. When I run the code nothing happens (the user tile is not changed).

Comment: A friend just pointed out that Windows 7 comes with .NET 3.5, I will just build the app for that. I'd still like to find an answer to this question though, and am willing to spend some time testing some ideas out if anyone has one, for sake of completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also have asked the author of that blog, he's a helpful guy, I know it because it's me :) You should check if your thread is in an STA apartment. Also you might need to call CoInitialize yourself, in .NET the framework does it for you but it's a prerequisite.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks fejesjoco,
I too was looking to convert the sample code from your blog to AutoIt and
couldn't get it to work.
The CoInitialize suggestion did it, you can find the AutoIt code in [this thread](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/127691-change-windows-profile-icon-tile/page__gopid__897164)
in the AutoIt forums.

```
$sUserName = "DOMAIN\rvdmast"
$sPicPath = "\\server\data\fotos\rvdmast.jpg"

; call CoInitialize
DLLCall("ole32.dll","int","CoInitialize","ptr",0)

$hPicPath = DLLStructCreate("wchar[128]")
DllStructSetData($hPicPath, 1, $sPicPath)

$hUserName = DLLStructCreate("wchar[128]")
DllStructSetData($hUserName, 1, $sUserName)

$aRet = DllCall(@SystemDir & "\shell32.dll", "long", 262, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($hUserName), "int", 0, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($hPicPath))

MsgBox(4096, "SetUserTile", $aRet[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The blog mentions that you need to specify the username in MACHINE\user or DOMAIN\user format. Other than that, I think you can use the relative picture path and you don't need to install it in shell32 (and then you probably won't need admin rights either), but try that once you get it working.

Comment: Unfortunately PVR\ahiscox still returns the same error. I had changed from relative paths because it wasn't working for me, and admin is used for the entire script, I just put it there so people knew it was running as admin. Of course I didn't make any of that clear in my question, so thanks for the comment :)